# Wildcard expression to search records in Dynamics CRM from an external app in Azure

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, query-expressions

I need to make a external web app that connects to Dynamics CRM. I need to make it on Azure and connected to Dynamics CRM online.

The real challenge is that I need to have a textbox in the web app, and my idea is while I write, I want to see account records of CRM. Additionally I want to use wildcards while I find (e. g. ABC* should be showing me instantly customers that start with ABC).

I am trying with queryexpression but I have not been able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ConditionOperator.Like

```
ConditionExpression condition1 = new ConditionExpression();
condition1.AttributeName = "attribute_name";
condition1.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
condition1.Values.Add(acc_name.ToLower() + "%");
```

Ref: https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/crm-2011-how-to-do-like-statement-in-queryexpression/